# How to add defer tag automatically in all javascript?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, deferred-loading

I'm using wordpress and i have many plugins which using javascript file.

I want to add "defer" tag in all javascript including inline script.

I don't wanna edit each file and add it manually.

So is there any code available like htaccess or some other code to add that tag automatically?

Thanks

Comment: manually is not that bad, you can use the "replace all" of any text editor. You can replace something by that + something else. ex: replace all `<p` to `<div><p` and all `/p>` with `/p></div>` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Apache since you reference .htaccess.  It's probably a bad idea, but maybe you can use [mod_ext_filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ext_filter.html).  There is an example there titled "Using sed to replace text in the response."  I guess you could try and replace `<script` with `<script defer`.